# Get the value that no match from the addition of other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array

**First**

```
array(
    0 => 100000,
    1 => 100000,
    2 => 100000,
    3 => 100000,
    4 => 100000,
    5 => 100000,
    6 => 100000,
    7 => 100000,
    8 => 100000
);
```

**Second**

```
array(
    0 => 500000,
    1 => 250000,
    2 => 150000
)
```

The problem is I want to have only the not matching value in the second array from addition first array.

**Example**

Second array index 0 which is 500000 can be obtained by addition from first array index 0 to 4 which is the value will be exact same 500000. Then 250000 and 150000 can't be obtained from addition first array because in addition to the first array it will be no exact value that matches 250000 and 150000

I want to achieve the value from the second array that has no matching value from the addition in the first array like this :

```
array(0=>250000, 1=>150000);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So effectively, you want to generate all possible sums from the values in the first array, then return the values in the second array which aren't in that set? If so, that would O(2^N) time to calculate (the power set). So it'll only run quickly when the first array is small.

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support to check for the sums of *any* combination of values from the first array, not just the sums of consecutive values, you'll need to find the sum of each member of the power set of the first array.

This function will generate an array of the sums of all power set members:

```
function generateArraySubsetSums($values)
{
    $numValues = count($values);
    $numSubsets = 2**$numValues;
    $sums = [];
    for ($subsetDef = 0; $subsetDef < $numSubsets; $subsetDef++) {
        $subsetSum = 0;
        for ($elementIndex = 0; $elementIndex < $numValues; $elementIndex++) {
            $isElementIncluded = ($subsetDef >> $elementIndex) & 1;
            if ($isElementIncluded) {
                $subsetSum += $values[$elementIndex];
            }
        }
        $sums[] = $subsetSum;
    }
    return array_unique($sums);
}
```

Then, to solve your actual question:

```
$first = [100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000];
$second = [500000, 250000, 150000];
$result = array_diff($second, generateArraySubsetSums($first));
```

This gives:

```
[2500000, 1500000]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Maybe this is the best solution for my case. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => 100000,
    1 => 100000,
    2 => 100000,
    3 => 100000,
    4 => 100000,
    5 => 100000,
    6 => 100000,
    7 => 100000,
    8=> 100000
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => 500000,
    1 => 250000,
    2 => 150000
);

$result = array();

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $total = 0;
    $flag = 0;

    foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
        $total += $v;
        if($total == $value)
        {
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($flag == 0)
    {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
print_r($result);
die();
```

It gives result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 250000
    [1] => 150000
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => 100000,
    1 => 100000,
    2 => 100000,
    3 => 100000,
    4 => 100000,
    5 => 100000,
    6 => 100000,
    7 => 100000,
    8=> 100000
);
$array2 = array(
    0 => 500000,
    1 => 250000,
    2 => 150000
);
```

**Solution**

```
$result = array();
foreach($array2 as $r){
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array1 as $r2){
        $total = $total+$r2;
        if($total==$r)break;
    }
    if($total!=$r)$result[] = $r;
    $total = 0;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 250000
    [1] => 150000
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.